# Android - Start Two Activities

Tags: java, android, xml, calendar

I've looked at a few questions on here and I never found an answer I like. I may not even need to launch two acitivies at the same time, but what I am trying to achieve is that on a button press, it brings up the calendar prepopulated with add ins for the reminders and to also move the view of my app to the next page. They'll see it when they confirm their reminder or cancel it and go back.

So really, the question is, how would I move my app to a new activity and also bring up the calendar with the info? I've been trying to do this onto one button to make it super simplistic, but it is not possible I can do it with two buttons...

Comment: Make the calendar a fragment. It then could easily be moved from view to view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the calendar activity from oncreate "next page activity". The "next page activity" won't load but will appear when going back.

If you don't want to always load the calendar from that activity you can pass a parameter and check it.

Comment: Oh! That's great! I honestly didn't think of that! That's the answer I was looking for. :) Thanks.